# Dark mode colors for Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design, uicolor, android-dark-theme

In the site [material.io](https://material.io/design/color/dark-theme.html) it is written that:

> To create branded dark surfaces, **overlay** the primary brand color at a low opacity over the recommended dark theme surface color (#121212). The color #1F1B24 is the result of combining the dark theme surface color #121212 and the **8% Primary color**.

[image: Brand Color]

My questions are:

1. How can I calculate 8% of my color?
2. How to implement this overlay thing in **Flutter**?

Answer (score 3):

A solution for the overlay without using widgets is to use [Color.alphaBlend](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/alphaBlend.html) which

> combine[s] the foreground color as a transparent color over top of a
>   background color, and return[s] the resulting combined color.

You use it like this:

```
Color newColor = Color.alphaBlend(foregroundColor, backgroundColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

1.8% of a color is the color but with 8% Opacity. This can be achieved by using the [Opacity widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Opacity-class.html) or by using the [withOpacity method of the Colors class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Color/withOpacity.html).

2.

> An overlay is a semi-transparent covering on an element, indicating state. Overlays provide a systematic approach to visualizing states using opacity.

To give an Overlay in Flutter use the [Overlay Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Overlay-class.html).

[example in flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets](https://medium.com/saugo360/https-medium-com-saugo360-flutter-using-overlay-to-display-floating-widgets-2e6d0e8decb9)

Answer (score 1):

1. `Color.fromRGBO(r, g, b, opacity)` Specifies the opacity. From 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque) in your case you might have opacity as 0.08 to simulate 8% opacity,
   so the code for you is `Color.fromRGBO(31, 26, 36, 0.08)`
2. The overlay can be implemented using a `Stack()` widget that is a positional widget that works very similar to Colum or Row, but Stack put each widget on top of another widget